# Не могу понять для чего используется th:action в SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

При запуске приложения и попытке сделать update для name выдаёт ошибку 405, такое уже было при попытке создать нового person, но ситуация разрешилась сама собой, помогите понять для чего используется th:action потому что мне кажется что ошибка именно здесь(или подскажите где она если я ошибаюсь).Строго не судите, приложение уровня "HelloWorld!" так как я учусь. Вот код программы

**Класс бина**

```
public class DataBase {

   private int auto_increment = 0 ;

   private ArrayList<Person> list;

   {
       list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add(new Person(++auto_increment,"Stas"));
       list.add(new Person(++auto_increment,"Nikita"));
       list.add(new Person(++auto_increment,"Alexandr"));
       list.add(new Person(++auto_increment,"Vitalyi"));
       list.add(new Person(++auto_increment,"Nadejda"));
   }

   public ArrayList<Person> getList() {
       return list;
   }
   public Person findPerson(int id ) {
       Person find = null;
       for(Person local: list) {
           if (id == local.getId()){
               find = local;
           }
       }
       return find;
   }
  public void save(Person person){
       person.setId(++auto_increment);
       list.add(person);
  }
  public void update(int id, Person updatePerson){
       Person personToBeUpdate = findPerson(id);
       personToBeUpdate.setName(updatePerson.getName());
  }
}
```

**Класс контроллер**

```
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {

   private DataBase dataBase;

   @Autowired
   public PersonController(DataBase dataBase) {
       this.dataBase = dataBase;
   }

   @GetMapping("/show")
   public String show(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("show", dataBase.getList());
       return "show";
   }

   @GetMapping("/{id}")
   public String personInfo(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("personInfo", dataBase.findPerson(id));
       return "personInfo";
   }

  @GetMapping("/new")
   public String newPerson(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("person",new Person()) ;
       return "new";
  }
    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute ("person")Person person){
       dataBase.save(person);
       return "redirect:/people/show";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String edit(Model model,@PathVariable("id") int id){
       model.addAttribute("person",dataBase.findPerson(id));
       return "edit";
    }
    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
   public String update(@ModelAttribute("person")Person person,@PathVariable("id") int id){
       dataBase.update(id, person);
       return "redirect:/people";
    }
}
```

**Представление**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>


<form th:method="PATCH" th:action="@{/people/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}" th:object="${person}">
   <label for="name"/>Enter Name </label>
   <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name"/>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Update!">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле HTML форма поддерживает только `GET` и `POST` методы отправки.
Чтобы обойти это ограничение, th:method добавляет в форму скрытое поле `_method` с именем оригинального метода (`DELETE`, `PATCH`, `PUT`).

В вашем случае он добавляет что-то вроде:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
```

В Spring есть фильтр `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, который понимает и обрабатывает это поле, т.е. передает запрос в нужный метод контроллера. Но по умолчанию он отключен, поэтому запрос приходит в контроллер, как `POST` — отсюда и ошибка 405 (Method not allowed).

Чтобы включить и автоматически сконфигурировать `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, добавьте в ваш `application.properties` строчку:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , но у меня нет файла Application.context вся конфигурация содержится в спринг приложении , подскажите, пожалуйста , что делать в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить в конфигурационный Java класс следующее:

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws 
    ServletException {
            super.onStartup(aServletContext);
            registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
        }
        private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
            aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
                    new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
        }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Бро этот вопрос я задавал 2 года назад, за это время в Spring Я  настолько преисполнился, что я как будто бы уже сто триллионов миллиардов лет проживаю на триллионах и

триллионах таких же приложений, мне этот код абсолютно
понятен, и я здесь ищу только одного - покоя, умиротворения и вот этой гармонии, от слияния с бесконечно вечным, от созерцания великого фрактального подобия и от вот этого замечательного всеединства существа, бесконечно вечного, куда ни посмотри, хоть вглубь - бесконечно
малое, хоть ввысь - бесконечное большое, понимаешь? А ты мне опять со своим вот этим, иди суе